# select a table column automatically in javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Similar to selecting a `table row`, can we select a `single column(Single cell)` of the `tableview` in `JavaFX` automatically?

Automatically, I mean, if I press `down arrow key`, only `single column` need to be selected instead of an `all columns of single row`

Thanks

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean. Do you mean that you want to select single cell or all cells of in one column? A table consist of rows, columns, and cells, and you need clarify exactly what you want to select. To me it sounds like you want to select all cells for a specific column, but it doesn't make sense to do this when you press `down arrow key`.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Does `table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);` accomplish what you want? It allows you to select single cells instead of entire rows.

Comment: that is correct, I tried that. but it is not selecting first column instead it is selecting third column by default

Comment: So you're saying you have selected a cell in the first column, and when you press the down key (you said `down key`, but I think you mean `right key`?) a cell in the third column is selected? To me, this doesn't make any sense. I think you should consider posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `cellSelectionEnabled` property of the selection model to `true`, you're able to select single cells.

Using the arrow keys you can move the selection selection to the cell next to the focused cell direction determined by the arrow.

```
// selection for single cells instead of single 
table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

// select third cell in first (possibly nested) column
table.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(2, table.getVisibleLeafColumn(0));

// focus the same cell
table.getFocusModel().focus(2, table.getVisibleLeafColumn(0));
```

Comment: Sorry, it worked for me. However, I made some changes in your code to make it working as I need to focus on first column.